# It140 project 2

Tags: python

I'm currently working on my project for IT140 where you use dictionaries, lists, and functions to create a text-based game. You have to move between rooms and pick up 6 objects to win the game; if you enter the room with the villain the game ends. I can move between rooms fine, but I can't get the items added to the inventory list. I've been watching videos to try to figure it out but I can't seem to find any fixes that will make the code run correctly. I haven't finished all of the code just yet, I'm just trying to troubleshoot the problem with appending the items to the list.  I'm still just learning python so any helpful criticism is greatly appreciated.

```
def instructions():
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('                   Mine Escape                    ')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('You must collect all 6 items to escape from the mine and save\n'
          'yourself and your boss. To move use the words south, east,\n'
          ' west, and north. To pickup items say get and the items name. \n'
          'if you enter the room with the lunatic and you have not \n'
          'collected all items, you will die. You win when you collect\n'
          'all 6 items. Good luck.')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')


def user_status():
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}')
    print(f'Inventory: {inventory}')
    print('You see ' + rooms[current_room]['Item'])



rooms = {
    'Top elevator shaft': {'South': 'Bottom elevator shaft', 'Item': 'nothing'},
    'Bottom elevator shaft': {'North': 'Top elevator shaft', 'West': 'Cart room',
                              'East': 'Cot room', 'Item': 'a flashlight'},
    'Cart room': {'East': 'Bottom elevator shaft', 'South': 'Extraction room', 'Item': 'a tourniquet'},
    'Extraction room': {'North': 'Cart room', 'Item': 'a bottle of rubbing alcohol'},
    'Cot room': {'West': 'Bottom elevator shaft', 'East': 'Map room', 'South': 'Tool room', 'Item': 'a roll of gauze'},
    'Map room': {'Villain': 'the lunatic', 'Item': 'nothing'},
    'Tool room': {'North': 'Cot room', 'South': 'Office room', 'Item': 'a can of food'},
    'Office room': {'North': 'Tool room', 'Item': 'a bottle of water'}
}


def move_rooms(direction, current_room):
    new_room = current_room
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        new_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
    else:
        print('There are no rooms this way.\n')
    return new_room


instructions()
current_room = 'Top elevator shaft'
inventory = []


while True:
    user_status()
    # direction
    direction = input('Enter a direction:\n').title()
    if direction == 'South' or direction == 'East' or direction == 'West' or direction == 'North':
        new_room = move_rooms(direction, current_room)
        current_room = new_room
    # item
    elif direction == 'Get ' + rooms[current_room]['Item']:
        if 'Item' not in inventory:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['Item'])
        elif 'Item' in inventory:
            print('You have already picked this item up.\n')
        else:
            print('Cant find that item\n')
    elif direction == 'Exit':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid direction.\n')
```

Comment: `'Item' not in inventory` checks whether the string "Item" is not inside the `inventory` list. Is that really what you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

You have small error in your if-conditions inside while-loop where you checking for Item presence in the inventory. Instead of checking if string representation of item in current room is in inventory, you just checking if string “Item” is in inventory.

Also, your if-conditions are logically wrong.

First of all, you don’t need to check if item is in the room, because `elif direction == 'Get ' + rooms[current_room]['Item']:` already ‘checks’ it - this block will be executed only if item, inputted in direction are the item that is in a current room. You either should change it to `elif direction.startswith(“Get”)` or remove checking item presence in a room completely.

Second: if Item not in inventory, then elif will be executed no matter what, you will never reach else block.

And one small advice:

```
if direction == "South" or direction == "East" …
```

is kind of ugly, better write just:

```
if direction in ("South", "East", "West", "North"):
```

This should fix your error:

```
while True:
    user_status()

    # direction
    direction = input('Enter a direction:\n').title()

    if direction in ("South", "East", "West", "North"):
        new_room = move_rooms(direction, current_room)
        current_room = new_room

    # item
    elif direction == 'Get ' + rooms[current_room]['Item']:
        if rooms[current_room]['Item'] not in inventory:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['Item'])
        else:
            print('You have already picked this item up.\n')

    elif direction == 'Exit':
        break

    else:
        print('Invalid direction.\n')
```